# Why does a query on a sparse index perform much faster than a query on a partial index in MongoDB?

Tags: index, mongodb

I created a sparse index in my MongoDB Atlas like so:

`db.detection_events.createIndex({"emp_id": 1}, {sparse: true})`

When I performed this operation:

`db.detection_events.count({"emp_id": {$exists: true}})`

I got the result extremely quickly. Upon readon the docs for sparse indeces, MongoDB [recommends to use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) partial indeces instead. I created a partial index like so:

`db.detection_events.createIndex({"emp_id": 1}, {partialFilterExpression: {emp_id: true}})`

And the same query takes a long time to execute. I got the partial index code from here.

Why does the partial index have a much higher query time than the sparse one? Is it because I created the index incorrectly?

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan The server version is 4.0.9

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I created the partial index incorrectly.

If you want to speed up an $exists query, you need to add the partialFilterExpression option like so:

`db.detection_events.createIndex({"thingToQueryOn": 1}, {partialFilterExpression: {thingToQueryOn: {$exists: true}}})`

Note the lack of quotation marks in the second document

Comment: It still seems slower than the sparse index version, but oh well

Comment: These should actually be equivalent. I suggest comparing the results of `explain('executionStats')` for a partial vs sparse index -- one possible difference could be whether index/data has already been loaded into RAM. If there is a difference in query plans, you could post both for comparison as a new question. The specific version of MongoDB server would also be relevant (but should be included in the query explain output).

Comment: @Stennie I believe you're right. I ran the test again today and am not noticing any difference in speed anymore. Maybe I ran it while it was still building the index or something?